# Angular + Bazel + Socket.IO: TypeError: decodePacket is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, socket.io, bazel

## Issue

I want to user Socket.IO with my Angular application. I build and run the app with Bazel.

However there is an error in the browser console when running the [dev server](https://github.com/flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue/blob/773ab1885d8790fed4800356dcb40bf787269749/client/BUILD.bazel#L59). Note that running the [prod server](https://github.com/flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue/blob/773ab1885d8790fed4800356dcb40bf787269749/client/BUILD.bazel#L173) works fine.

I think that the error is caused by `node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transport.js` line 95.

```
onData(data) {
  const packet = parser.decodePacket(data, this.socket.binaryType);
  this.onPacket(packet);
}
```

That's most likey because `parser`, which is imported from `engine.io-parser` doesn't use the browser libs. So we probably need to patch it in such a way that it uses the browser libs.

The actual error in the console is:

```
ERROR TypeError: decodePacket is not a function
    at Object.decodePayload (ts_scripts.js?v=89114305:17072)
    at XHR.onData (ts_scripts.js?v=89114305:15937)
    at Request.<anonymous> (ts_scripts.js?v=89114305:15559)
    at Request.Emitter.emit (ts_scripts.js?v=89114305:14385)
```

## Minimal Reproduction

You can try it yourself here: [flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue](https://github.com/flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue/tree/773ab1885d8790fed4800356dcb40bf787269749)

**Dev**

```
yarn client:dev
yarn server:dev
```

throws error in browser console

**Prod**

```
yarn client:prod
yarn server:prod
```

works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `engine.io-parser+4.0.1.patch` patch fixed it

```
diff --git a/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js b/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js
index a412b46..b9f7d50 100644
--- a/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js
+++ b/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-const encodePacket = require("./encodePacket");
-const decodePacket = require("./decodePacket");
+const encodePacket = require("./encodePacket.browser");
+const decodePacket = require("./decodePacket.browser");

 const SEPARATOR = String.fromCharCode(30); // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text
```

Thanks to [Ramil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11253793/ray)

See [this commit](https://github.com/flolu/angular-bazel-socketio3-issue/commit/a51298ef6653fff2806b254eda548e25d67ebb71) for more information